# Swift inheritance of singleton pattern?

Tags: swift, inheritance, singleton, swift4, swift-class

Have this class which is never used directly, only inherited:

```
class ApiBase {}
```

How do I define a generic static singleton `default` here? - So I can:

```
class FooApi: ApiBase {}  // Want only one instance of `FooApi`
class BarApi: ApiBase {}  // Want only one instance of `BarApi`

FooApi.default.foo_api_only_method_name()
BarApi.default.bar_api_only_method_name()
```

The only thing I can think of is to create a `protocol` which `FooApi` and `BarApi` need to implement. But that seems suboptimal, would prefer to write an implementation like:

```
func `default`<T: ApiBase>() -> T {
    if staticInstance == nil {
        staticInstance = T()
    }
    return staticInstance
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding an interface:

```
protocol Instance {
    associatedtype T
    // static var _instance: T {get set}  # Can't use; can't override :(
    static func instance() -> T
}
```

Usable like so:

```
class ApiBase: Instance {
    var root: String = ""

    static var _instance: ApiBase = ApiBase()

    open class func instance() -> ApiBase {
        if _instance.root == "" {
            _instance = ApiBase()
        }
        return _instance
    }
}
```

Inheritance:

```
class FooApi: ApiBase {
    static var _fooApi: FooApi = FooApi()

    override class func instance() -> FooApi {
        if _fooApi.root == "" {
            _fooApi = FooApi()
        }
        return _instance
    }
}
```

This is suboptimal, as the body's of the `instance` functions are identical in pattern. But it works.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow what this solution is providing you that static lets in each subclass wouldn’t be doing with less code? Can you explain I’m curious but also glad you found a solution.

Comment: The thing is, I want to contract `class`es to conform to an interface; one which requires it to implement the Singleton pattern. `static let`s wouldn't let the instance be redefined. The instance needs to be re-definable because the `.root` value is taken at runtime (from `UserDefaults`), and can be changed so I need to recreate all the objects. Also using the `static let`s like you answered, won't conform to any interface.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a way to solve this using generics but my suggestion would be to put

```
static let `default` = FooApi()
```

and

```
static let `default` = BarApi()
```

into the two subclasses. That way each would create its own singleton without too much additional code.

Comment: This is absolutely the preferred solution. Generics would be the wrong tool here, and mixing protocols (i.e. `Self`) with class inheritance is Pandora's box in Swift. There is no reason to create complexity to try to avoid one clear line of code.

Comment: but the superclass Singleton should contain a private init, so that's not possible, right?